# trouble passing API result to chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js, fetch-api

When I fetch the API everything is working but when I put the function in the data holder of chart, it shows the error in console. I don't know what is wrong because when I do individual check, I can see all the numbers but when I put that function in data field it doesn't. I also posted the sample API.

What's going wrong?

```js
const api = "http://localhost:8080/webmap/api/chartforweek/username1";

let chartForOneWeek = [];

function showAll() {
  fetch(api)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((oneWeekChar) => {
      chartForOneWeek = oneWeekChar;
      console.table(chartForOneWeek);


    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
}

function showUser() {
  chartForOneWeek.forEach(oneweek => {
    oneweek.averageDose;

  });
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'apples',
      data: showUser(), //==========> I tried putting this in here and I tried [showUser] and I also tried [chartForOneWeek.averageDose] //

      backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.4)"
    }, {
      label: 'oranges',
      data: [], //=====> what should I put for data?
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.4)"
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.min.js"></script>

</canvas><canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

This is sample API data:

```
[
  {
    "currentTime": null,
    "date": {
      "year": 2019,
      "month": "APRIL",
      "dayOfMonth": 10,
      "dayOfWeek": "WEDNESDAY",
      "era": "CE",
      "dayOfYear": 100,
      "leapYear": false,
      "monthValue": 4,
      "chronology": {
        "id": "ISO",
        "calendarType": "iso8601"
      }
    },
    "userName": "username1",
    "currentMeal": 0.0,
    "currentBloodSugar": 0.0,
    "currentDose": 0.0,
    "averageDose": 2.56,
    "averageBloodSugar": 110.0
  }
```

Comment: Possible typo: `</canvas><canvas id="myChart"></canvas>`.

Comment: What happens in `showUser()`? It looks incomplete. Do you call the API from inside of `forEach(oneweek => {`

Comment: When I fetch the API and the showUser() will print out the array of average dose

Comment: Where do you call `showAll()`?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that fetch is an async call, it hasn't finished before you create the chart. You need to do some kind of await before proceeding.

["Synchronous" fetch with async/await](https://dev.to/johnpaulada/synchronous-fetch-with-asyncawait)

Comment: Agreed. I would initialize the chart *after* receiving the data. But it's not really clear to me where the OP is calling the API.